# Google cloud not recognizing header with string column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

When I try to create a dataset in Bigquery it is not able to autodetect my header (which is the first row) since I have a column containing only string values. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Are you trying to detect column names or infer the schema? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let Google BigQuery infer schema from csv string file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769198/let-google-bigquery-infer-schema-from-csv-string-file)